# cURL Request: POST data is received by server, but returns invalid request

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to query the NOTAM database (https://www.notams.faa.gov) in order to have the server parse the NOTAMs for display on a map, code is PHP.

I'm using cURL to send the POST data, however, the server is returning an "invalid request".  Here is the POST data I'm sending to the server.  It is exactly what is sent during a request from the homepage (discovered using Fiddler).  The NOTAMs needed are the "RKRR" ICAO (airport code for Incheon Center here in Korea).

What am I missing here?

```
$url = "https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/queryRetrievalMapAction.do";
$ch = curl_init($url);

$header = array('Host: www.notams.faa.gov', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',      'Connection: keep-alive', 'Cache-Control: max-age=0', 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36', 'Referer: https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/', 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate', 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Origin: https://www.notams.faa.gov');

$data = 'retrieveLocId=rkrr&reportType=Raw&submit=View+NOTAMSs&actionType=notamRetriealByICAOs';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have a typo in variable `$data` value

> $data = 'retrieveLocId=rkrr&reportType=Raw&submit=View+NOTAMSs&actionType=notamRetriealByICAOs';

Its actually

> $data = 'retrieveLocId=rkrr&reportType=Raw&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs&submit=View+NOTAMSs';

Its not `notamRetriealByICAOs`

its     `notamRetrievalByICAOs`

Give a try

Comment: Haha, thank you.  This was driving me crazy...  

At least this is an example of a valid POST request with cURL!